# No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to shuffle an array, but I get a   "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:' on the last statement.

How should bArray be declared?

```
NSArray *bArray;
```

and in

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
      [self shuffleb];
```

then

```
-(void) shufflb
   {
 bArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"ca",
             @"do",
             @"ba",
             @"tr",
             @"bu",
             @"bl",
             @"bo",
             @"pu",
             nil];

NSInteger count = [bArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
    NSInteger nElements = count - i;
    n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [bArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exchangeObjectAtIndex` is a method of NSMutableArray.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Use modern Objective-C (it makes your code read better)
2. The method you want to use is only present on NSMutableArray, so create a mutable array or a mutable copy of an NSArray (below):

   ```
   bArray = [@[@"ca", @"do", @"ba", @"tr", @"bu", @"bl",@"bo", @"pu"] mutableCopy];
   ```

Comment: Please pay attention that if you rewrite your code to new syntax, you need to remove the `nil`! Just a remark.

Comment: That's why the nil is not there anymore. Or did you just want to emphasize that fact?